# Function arguments php not working

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdo

So, I'm trying to get the name of a forum title through a function by using the `category_id` in the url.

It's not returning the title. Yes, I am including the `functions.php`.

The link is:

```
http://www.dxbridge.com/view_category.php?cid=1
```

functions.php:

```
function getForumsCategoriesName($cid) {

    $query = "SELECT * FROM categories WHERE id='" . $cid . "'";

    try {
        global $db;
        // Execute the query against the database
        $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
        foreach($result as $forums) {
            $forumsID = $forums['id'];
            $forumsTitle = $forums['category_title'];
            $forumsTopicAmount = $forums['topic_amount'];
            $forumsCategoriesName = "<h1>" . $forumsTitle . "</h1>";
            echo $forumsCategories3;
        }
    }
    catch(PDOException $ex) { 
        // Note: On a production website, you should not output $ex->getMessage(). 
        // It may provide an attacker with helpful information about your code.  
        die("Error loading names"); 
    }
}
```

trying to grab the name from function

```
$cid = $_GET['cid'];
getForumsCategoriesName($cid);
```

Also, I know the variable is being set, it's jsut not going through the function.

Comment: Your variable `echo $forumsCategories3;` doesn't have a value. You have several other variables populated there, but not that one.

Comment: Always when developing code, turn on PHP's error display. It would be complaining about an undefined variable `$forumsCategories3`.  At the top of you script:  `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: @Ghost points this out below - you are getting _none_ of the security benefit of PDO by passing `$cid` right into your SQL string. Now is the time to learn to use `prepare()/execute()` properly with bound parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't returned/echoed anything (actually you echoed something, an undefined variable). Bind the value, don't directly inject it on the query string:

```
function getForumsCategoriesName($cid) 
{ 
    $result = array();
    try {
        global $db;

        // Execute the query against the database
        $query = 'SELECT * FROM categories WHERE id = :cid '; // put a named placeholder
        $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
        $stmt->bindParam(':cid', $cid); // bind the value
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        return $result; // return the values
        // echo $forumsCategories3; // this doesn't make sense, its undefined.
    }
    catch(PDOException $ex) { 
        // Note: On a production website, you should not output $ex->getMessage(). 
        // It may provide an attacker with helpful information about your code.  
        die("Error loading names"); 
    }
}
```

Then on usage:

```
$cid = $_GET['cid'];
$result = getForumsCategoriesName($cid);

foreach($result as $forums) {
    $forumsID = $forums['id'];
    $forumsTitle = $forums['category_title'];
    $forumsTopicAmount = $forums['topic_amount'];
    $forumsCategoriesName = "<h1>" . $forumsTitle . "</h1>";

    echo $forumsID . '<br/>'; // echo everybody else

}
```